# How do I give a input a variable and export it

Tags: html, forms, search

I am trying to make a search engine.

I was expecting it to redirect me.
Heres my code

```
<!doctype html>
<script>
   function show(){
         s=searchForm.searchField.value;
         window.location.replace("https://www.google.com/search?q="+searchField);
      }
</style>
   <form id="searchForm">
         <input type="search" name="searchField" placeholder="Search QuickSearch">
         <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="show()">
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is something like this:

JS:

```
function show() {
  const s = document.getElementById('inputId').value;
  window.location.replace("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + s);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="searchForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">
        <input type="search" name="searchField" id="inputId" placeholder="Search QuickSearch">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="show()">
    </form>
```

Comment: https://quickmash.github.io/search/ is the url if you want to see it work

Comment: HELP WITH THE CONSTRUCTION AT https://github.com/QuickMash/search

Comment: i did not understood what do you need?

Comment: Its done but your welcome to help with the development on GitHub. [Click here](https://github.com/QuickMash/search/blob/main/)

Comment: It works sooooooo well